# Не открывается админка в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Сайт был перенесен с одного хостинга на другой. Сайт открывается а админка нет.

Сайт - http://technosector.kz

Админка - http://technosector.kz/wp-admin/

Правил после переноса только один файл в корне wp-config.php . Что может быть?

Comment: смотрите логи сервера

Comment: может файлы админки не переписались, проверьте

Comment: А что вы правили в wp-config?

Comment: См ошибки http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD